# Find out average statistics in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I find average statistics in Google App Engine? For example, I would like to know the average number of requests per second.

Comment: in their cloud console page.

Comment: @ZigMandel yeah, but for example there is not the average number of requests over time